# Python analogue of "ktensor" function from matlab

Tags: python, matlab

Is there any Python package that can build tensor by calculating outer products of matrix columns?

Like "ktensor" function from matlab

https://www.tensortoolbox.org/ktensor_doc.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the `parafac` function from the `tensorly` package. From their [documentation](http://tensorly.org/stable/user_guide/tensor_decomposition.html):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorly as tl
tensor = tl.tensor([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

from tensorly.decomposition import parafac
factors = parafac(tensor, rank=2)
```

`factors` now holds the list of matrices that form the decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer, you can use [TensorLy](http://tensorly.org/dev/index.html) for manipulating tensors, including tensors in CP form ("Kruskal tensors"). The [`tensorly.kruskal_tensor` module](http://tensorly.org/dev/modules/api.html#module-tensorly.kruskal_tensor) handles these particular operations.

If you want to reconstruct a Kruskal tensor from the factors (and optional vector of weights), you can use `kruskal_to_tensor` from TensorLy:

```
full_tensor = kruskal_to_tensor(kruskal_tensor)
```

or, equivalently:

```
full_tensor = kruskal_to_tensor((weights, factors))
```

If your decomposition has rank K, weights is a vector of length R and factors a list of factors with R columns each.

You can also directly use the underlying functions such as [outer-product](https://github.com/tensorly/tensorly/blob/master/tensorly/tenalg/outer_product.py) or [Khatri-Rao](http://tensorly.org/dev/modules/generated/tensorly.tenalg.khatri_rao.html#tensorly.tenalg.khatri_rao).

As mentioned in the previous answer, if you have a full tensor, you can apply CP ([parafac](http://tensorly.org/dev/modules/generated/tensorly.decomposition.parafac.html#tensorly.decomposition.parafac)) decomposition to approximate the factors.